# Как сделать область 960px в фиксированном блоке

Tags: html, css

Есть такая верстка:

```css
body {
 width: 1300px;
 max-width: 1300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2500px;
}

header {
 padding: 0px 0px;
 display: flex;
 width: 960px;
 background: red;
}
header .logo {
 width: 170px;
}
header .logo .textBig {
 font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #ff0000;
}
header .logo span.hashtag {
 color: #000;
}
header .logo .textMin {
 margin-top: -7px;
 color: #bcbcbc;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 00px;
}
header .fix {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99999;
 /*background: #fff;*/
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="fix">
    <div class="logo">
     <div class="textBig"><span class="hashtag">#</span>Логотип</div>
     <div class="textMin">слоган</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>

  <div class="page">
   <h1>Очень найкрутейший супер-пупер заголовок страницы</h1>

   <div class="imagePost">
    <div class="cardPost">
     <div class="preView">
      <div class="title">Очень краткое название информативное статьи</div>
      <div class="opis">Описание статьи. Описание статьи, описание статьи, и еще раз это же самое описание этой чудесной статьи...</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Получается что страница идет по центру, и ее ширина 960px, а фиксированная шапка должна быть на весь экран всегда, но так чтобы контент в ней был на 960px, и был по центру (а сейчас логотип прижат к левому краю).

Если убрать в **header .fix {** `left:0;` тогда получается что шапка уже не дотягивает до левого края.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: можно поместить шапку в отдельный блок шириной 100% и сделать его по центру

Comment: @spais можете привести пример с моим кодом? я вроде бы пробовал так, не вышло.

Comment: уже колдую, скоро скорее всего будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так

```css
body {
 width: 1300px;
 max-width: 1300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background: #fff;
}
.container
{
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background: #ff4444;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2500px;
}

header {
 padding: 0px 0px;
 display: flex;
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
 
}
header .logo {
 width: 170px;
}
header .logo .textBig {
 font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #ff0000;
}
header .logo span.hashtag {
 color: #000;
}
header .logo .textMin {
 margin-top: -7px;
 color: #bcbcbc;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 00px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <header>
  <div class="fix">
   <div class="logo">
    <div class="textBig"><span class="hashtag">#</span>Логотип</div>
    <div class="textMin">слоган</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  

  <div class="page">
   <h1>Очень найкрутейший супер-пупер заголовок страницы</h1>

   <div class="imagePost">
    <div class="cardPost">
     <div class="preView">
      <div class="title">Очень краткое название информативное статьи</div>
      <div class="opis">Описание статьи. Описание статьи, описание статьи, и еще раз это же самое описание этой чудесной статьи...</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь, что я Вас правильно понял.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/vbxJpY)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 2000px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo_box h1::before {
  content: '#';
  color: red;
}

.logo_box span {
  color: #bcbcbc;
}

main {
  padding-top: 73px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo_box">
      <h1>Логотип</h1>
      <span>Слоган</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Something...</h2>
  </div>
</main>
```